# CSS targeting and override the styles of an element using different rules

Tags: html, css

I have two type of cells in my table.

1st type cells have the class name ".top"

2nd type cells have the class name ".top .selected"

My problem is I have to remove the border-top in my 2nd type of cells.

here is my code:but it not apply the 2nd code.

**1st Type:**

```
html body #ROOT tr.fare .top {
border-top: 3px solid #888888 !important;
}
```

**2nd type:**

```
html body #ROOT tr.fare .top .selected{
border-top: none !important;
}
```

I can not remove **!important** tag from 1st type.I want to override the 1st property and apply the 2nd type css.Please advice me, How to target strongly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation it sounds like the cells which are selected have both classes top and selected.

In which case you rule should look like this:

```
html body #ROOT tr.fare .top.selected{ /* no space between top and selected */
    border-top: none;
}
```

The space makes a big difference.

```
.top .selected
{
  ...
}
```

The above selector means: Select all elements with the class name selected that are decendents of the element with an class top.

However the following selector

```
.top.selected
{
  ...
}
```

means: Select the element which has class selected and also a class name of top.

Answer (score 1):

You should write this in CSS:

```
html body #ROOT tr.fare .top.selected{
border-top: none !important;
}
```

Remove space between .top and .selected

**.top.selected** = element which is having both the classes

**.top .selected** = .top element which is having  inside another element with .selected class.